How do I avoid .then or repeated await when chaining promises in TypeScript?
I wrote some code to wrap the Playwright Page to simplify a few operations.  In one of my operations, I wanted to do something like typing and tabbing (this simulates the user behaviour better even if it is slower for Playwright so it's primarily to test that tab order works as expected).
The class to wrap would be something like this:
import { Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test";
class SimplePage {
  constructor(private readonly page: Page) {}
  async type(text: string): Promise<this> {
    await this.page.keyboard.type(text);
    return this;
  }
  async tab(): Promise<this> {
    await this.page.keyboard.press("Tab");
    return this;
  }  
}

At present the only way I can use this in my code is as follows:
await myPage.type(programName)
  .then((p) => p.tab())
  .then((p) => p.type(shortName))
  .then((p) => p.tab());

or
await myPage.type(programName);
await myPage.tab();
await myPage.type(shortName);
await myPage.tab();

I was wondering if there's anyway to construct it so the following would work
await myPage
  .type(programName)
  .tab()
  .type(shortName)
  .tab();


Yes that's possible, but the methods would have to return SimplePage & Promise, and correctly manage the chaining internally.

There's https://github.com/hdorgeval/playwright-fluent but I wouldn't actually use this overly-clever trick--the code is incomprehensible to normal people and hard to debug and maintain. Just use the vanilla Playwright syntax so it's readable and unsurprising.

I am only after it for the keyboard tbh, not for the whole thing as you stated it was incomprehensible

You could give your SimplePage class a promise property, and at every call of tab or text, replace that promise with the new chained promise.
Finally, make SimplePage a thenable, by defining a then method. This way it will respond as expected to an await operator:
class SimplePage {
  private promise: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve();

  constructor(private readonly page: Page) {}

  type(text: string): SimplePage {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(() => this.page.keyboard.type(text));
    return this;
  }

  tab(): SimplePage {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(() => this.page.keyboard.press("Tab"));
    return this;
  }

  then(onFulfill: (value: any) => void, onReject: (error: any) => void) {
    return this.promise.then(onFulfill, onReject);
  }
}

Implementing PromiseLike:
The type declaration for then would be:
class SimplePage implements PromiseLike<void> {
  private promise: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve();

  constructor(private readonly page: Page) {}

  type(text: string): SimplePage {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(() => this.page.keyboard.type(text));
    return this;
  }

  tab(): SimplePage {
    this.promise = this.promise.then(() => this.page.keyboard.press("Tab"));
    return this;
  }

  then<TResult1, TResult2>(
      onfulfilled?: ((value: void) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, 
      onrejected?:  ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | null | undefined
      ): PromiseLike<TResult1|TResult2> {
    return this.promise.then(onfulfilled, onrejected);
  }
}


can you give an example of the code that uses this?

The code that you have given in the question is supposed to work with this. See a reduced example on replit.com where I have used a mock implementation of Page.

Took a bit to understand how this worked but interesting about the then at the end.

I wonder what the proper typing for then would be to make it pass with implemented PromiseLike<void>

See addition to answer.
